# smartdiagram: How to remove gradient from background color?

Tags: smartdiagram

I'm drawing this:

[image]

How can I remove the gradient in the background of each node? I want to set a solid color for each element.

Code for the above example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
  every shadow/.style={
    fill=none,
    shadow xshift=0pt,
    shadow yshift=0pt}
}
\smartdiagramset{
  module shape=rectangle,
  uniform arrow color=true,
  uniform color list=teal!60 for 5 items,
  arrow color=gray!50!black,
  back arrow distance=0.75cm,
  module y sep=2cm,
  module minimum width=4cm,
  text width=4cm,
  border color=none
}
\smartdiagram[flow diagram]{
  a,
  b,
  c,
  d,
  e
}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer proposed by @Christian Hupfer works great but is limited to one color. In the source code of the smartdiagram package, the current color is referenced as **\col**. Hence, the following code allows the use the **set color list** parameter:

```
\tikzset{module/.append style={top color=\col,bottom color=\col}}
```

The resulting code creates a diagram without gradient inside the nodes but with the chosen colors as @L42 requested.

[image: diagram without color gradient]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\begin{document}


\tikzset{
  every shadow/.style={
    fill=none,
    shadow xshift=0pt,
    shadow yshift=0pt}
}
\tikzset{module/.append style={top color=\col,bottom color=\col}}

\smartdiagramset{
  module shape=rectangle,
  uniform arrow color=true,
  set color list={red!10, blue!30, blue!30, blue!30, green!40},
  arrow color=gray!50!black,
  back arrow distance=0.75cm,
  module y sep=2cm,
  module minimum width=4cm,
  text width=4cm,
  border color=none,
}
\smartdiagram[flow diagram]{
  a,
  b,
  c,
  d,
  e
}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

One way is to use the `module./style=` option, but appending the `top color` and `bottom color` to have the same value.

The backdraw is that you've have to specify again the colors.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\begin{document}


\tikzset{
  every shadow/.style={
    fill=none,
    shadow xshift=0pt,
    shadow yshift=0pt}
}

\tikzset{module/.append style={top color=teal!60,bottom color=teal!60}}
\smartdiagramset{
  module shape=rectangle,
  uniform arrow color=true,
  uniform color list=teal!60 for 5 items,
  arrow color=gray!50!black,
  back arrow distance=0.75cm,
  module y sep=2cm,
  module minimum width=4cm,
  text width=4cm,
  border color=none,
}
\smartdiagram[flow diagram]{
  a,
  b,
  c,
  d,
  e
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. This works for what I had in mind, but can I use this approach if I need multiple colors?

Comment: @L42: Hm, unsure -- which colours do you want to modify?

Comment: Say I want a, b and c to be teal and the rest be blue?

Comment: @L42: I'll take a lot (and sorry for the late response!)

Comment: I'll have no clue for this yet

Comment: Thanks for checking it out, Christian. I will use another package if I end up needing different colors for the nodes.